# c++ create dynamic type

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion, custom-data-type

I have the following situation: Depending on some parameter that my function takes it have to create different types:

I want to do something like this:

```
if(variant==1){
    #define my_type int;
}
else{
    #define my_type double;
}
cout<<sizeof(my_type);
```

and then use my_type in my further code.

So, that in case of variant=1 `sizeof(my_type)` gives 4 and for variant=2 it gives 8.

How can this be done? Either in this manner or another.

Thanks.

Comment: The way you suggest cannot work, since `#define` works in compile time, but `if` works in run time. It is hard to suggest what you should do without knowing more about your problem. Can you tell us a bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That's not how preprocessor directives work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Magnus Hoff in that what you asked cannot be done. But there are two approximations.

Option 1: make variant a macro.

```
#ifdef variant
#  define my_type int
#else
#  define my_type double
#endif
```

Option 2: use template function.

Instead of

```
void func(int variant) {
  if (variant==1)
    #define my_type int
  else
    #define my_type double
  my_type ...
}
```

do this:

```
template<typename my_type> void func() {
  my_type ...
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with corresponding example. I thing neither of these above will fit me.

Comment: The template solution should work with your updated question. In the function body, you may use size_of(my_type).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
if(variant==1){
    #define my_type int;
}
else{
    #define my_type double;
}
cout<<sizeof(my_type);
```

… with this:

```
template< class Type >
void foo()
{
    // ...
    cout<<sizeof(Type);
}

// ...
if( variant==1 )
{
    foo<int>();
}
else
{
    foo<double>();
}
```

Note that a runtime value can't affect compile time decisions. Without a time travel device.